# Cannot resolve declaration or definition 'xlink:XLINKEXT' while using xlink

Tags: xml, xsd

I Using xlink in an xsd or schema but getting the following error. I have imported the xlind.xsd correctly but getting the below error:

```
xlink:XLINKEXT' must refer to an existing group.
    Error location: xs:schema / xs:element / xs:complexType / xs:choice / xs:group / @ref
    Details
        src-resolve.4.2: Cannot resolve declaration or definition 'xlink:XLINKEXT'.
```

XSD :

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" schemaLocation="rdf.xsd"/>
<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" schemaLocation="xlink.xsd"/>


    <xs:element name="refdm">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="applic" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:group ref="ALLDMC"/>
                <xs:element ref="issno" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element ref="dmtitle" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:group ref="xlink:XLINKEXT" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:choice>
        <xs:attribute name="target" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attributeGroup ref="bodyatt"/>
        <xs:attributeGroup ref="xlink:XLINKATT"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Please help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

There are no such things `XLINKEXT` and `XLINKATT` in XLink schema. How do you come to these names in first place?

You most probably need `xlink:extendedModel` and `xlink:extendedAttrs`.

Comment: I Got this from my client but I think names are changed.

Comment: <xs:group name="XLINKEXT">
  <xs:choice>
   <xs:element ref="xlink:resource"/>
   <xs:element ref="xlink:locator"/>
   <xs:element ref="xlink:arc"/>
  </xs:choice>
 </xs:group>

Comment: I think xlink.xsd is customized as per requirement.

Comment: @user3419276 Correct your "customized" XLink schema.

Comment: The xlink.xs is correct and valid and I think the issue is with namespace.But not getting any solution

Comment: Should I use the original Xlink.xsd as shown by you?